# how the redirect in grails controller works

Tags: grails-2.0, grails-controller

I am using redirect to pass the model object from one method to another method in grails. How can I get the values of that model object in another method.

See my code here

```
redirect(controller:"inquiry", action:"createSSVInvestigation", model: [inquiryInstance:inquiryInstance], params:['inquiry.id':inquiryInstance.id])
```

So in the action `createSSVInvestigation` how can I get the values of `inquiryInstance` object.

Answer (score 4):

```
redirect(controller:"inquiry", action:"createSSVInvestigation",params:['inquiryId':inquiryInstance.id])
```

In createSSVInvestigation action,We get the id of inquiryInstance by `params.inquiryId`.

```
def createSSVInvestigation(){
    def inquiryInstance= InquiryClassname.get(params.inquiryId)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use params to pass all your objects/variables and access them from your params in `createSSVInvestigation` action. Also model is not part of redirect parameters [here](http://grails.org/doc/2.2.1/ref/Controllers/redirect.html).

```
redirect(controller:"inquiry", action:"createSSVInvestigation", params: [...])
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
flash.chainModel.inquiryInstance
```

Update:
The original question was to get `inquiryInstance` which was set in model. In [documentation](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/3.0.x/ref/Controllers/chain.html) its mentioned that we should use flash memory. So this is a way to access flash variables once you chain controllers.

Comment: Please explain your solution.